# Verify ssl certificate in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

How can I verify SSL certificate on https of given domain by NodeJS?

I need to know if user open this like is it trusted or should add it as exception?

--

I think this code should raise error during unsigned or selfsigned certificate.

```
var https = require('https');

var options = {
  host: 'daarkoob.ir',
  port: 2222,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET',
  rejectUnauthorized:true
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
  console.log("headers: ", res.headers);
});
req.end();

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

https://daarkoob.ir:2222 is self signed certificated,so above code should raise error during surfing.but nothing happened.

Comment: Did you look at the options for `request`? http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.7.8/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback `rejectUnauthorized` verifies cert against list of CAs.

Comment: @WiredPrairie: Yeah,but this is not work for me.question edited.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:
`rejectUnauthorized`: If `true`, the server certificate is verified against
  the list of supplied CAs. An `'error'` event is emitted if verification
  fails. Verification happens at the connection level, *before* the HTTP
  request is sent. Default `true`.

I guess that you need to specify a list of CA or the option is ignored.

Comment: So node doesn't bundle cacert.pem?

Comment: Actually it is bundled: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_root_certs.h